# How to redirect URL of kind node/nid to its url alias

Tags: path-aliases

I want to replicate the effect seen in http://www.drupal.org/node/1 , where you are redirected to drupal.org/about.

I have a fresh Drupal 7 installation, I create a node with a path, and don't get the effect. I have tried with module Path Auto, and nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried with module [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) and I have achieved the desired results. I had thought it eliminated erroneously duplicated URLs, but it seems that it goes further to "hide" system path if an alias-url is set.

The problems stated in the documentation page itself, about incompatibilities with multilingual sites: I had found a problem of infinite reloop, but it was my fault; it was caused by a directory named "en" which is a very bad idea if you have languages set at suffixes in the URL, so it will cause the path to be www.example.com/en/ instead of www.example.com/en , thus doing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you've figured out a great solution, [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) may well be a module that can help you out with this for other problems you have in the future. Rules contains several options to fire off several events. For example, if you tell Rules to React on event `Content is viewed`, you can then set certain events, conditions, and actions. One of these Events will cause the user to be redirected to another page - not as simple as Global Redirect, but if there's something you need done before redirecting, this could do a lot for you.